# CATransform3DRotate flip horizontal

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, catransform3d

I have a layer that I need to transform. Currently I am using the following:

```
self.customLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity,M_PI / 2.0f, 0, 0, 1);
```

This correctly makes the layer right side up, but it also needs to be flipped horizontally, since it is the wrong way.  How can I adjust `CATransform3DRotate` to do this?

Comment: Can you explain more the current result you have hand the desired result?

Comment: It just needs to be flipped horizontally, not sure how else to explain it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need:

```
self.customLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0f, 0, 0, 1),
                                                -1, 1, 1);
```

A scale with -1 is a flip. Imagine you're squashing the image horizontally and you go past zero.

Comment: It is giving me the following error: Passing 'int' to parameter of incompatible type 'CATransform3D' and a warning: Implicit declaration of function CATransform3DMakeRotate is invalid in C99.

Comment: @NicHubbard - It should be `CATransform3DMakeRotation` and not `CATransform3DMakeRotate`. +1

Comment: @NicHubbard ok, sounds like we've flipped in the wrong direction. Try `CATransform3DScale(/* rotation */, 1, -1, 1)`

Comment: (btw, 'flip horizontal' generally means flipping in the x direction, that is, around the y axis)

Answer (score 7):

Since the parameter here is

```
CATransform3DScale (CATransform3D t, CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy, CGFloat sz)
```

If you want to flip horizontally, you should not provide any vector value in CATransform3DMakeRotation(). Instead, you want to just control the scale of x-axis.

By flipping it horizontally you should:

```
self.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                        -1, 1, 1);
```

If you want to flip it back to origin, you do:

```
self.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                        1, 1, 1);
```

Addition:
A shorter version will save you one operation. To flip:

```
self.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
```

To flip back to normal:

```
self.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: how can i add this transform with animation in CALayer?

Answer (score 4):

I personally find it better readable to use KVC for these things. You could probably use something like the following to achieve the same effect:

```
// Rotate the layer 90 degrees to the left
[self.customLayer setValue:@-1.5707 forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
// Flip the layer horizontally
[self.customLayer setValue:@-1 forKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
```